# router tilting mechanism

Tags: design, mechanism, rotation, routing

I am trying to design a very rigid tilting mechanism for my router. For this purpose I had a look at table saws, which seem to be supported by 2 mechanisms, one in front, one at the back, called "trunnions".

Such a trunnion consists of part of a circle, with a circular precision ground track, and a mating mart. The part of the circle is as such that the center of rotation coincides with the surface of the table.

However, when looking for "trunnion", I find medieval cannons as well as brand/product-specific constructions, which seem rather expensive. Does such a mechanism have other names? The router in question is a 20kg model, just as an indication of size. My last attempt was "circular track bearing", but i doubt that i am looking in the right direction.

Could anyone provide a pointer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search circular motion guide.  or curved linear guide. THK's HCR product is one example.

This assumes you want to move the router while cutting. If you will lock it down, someone could cut and weld you a trunnion out of steel plate a lot cheaper than it would cost to design and fab the structure needed to mount the circular rail.